# Declaring variable vars inside a PHP class?

Tags: php, oop

I am a noob with OOP, and would appreciate some help on what must be an exceedingly simple problem.

In non-OOP PHP, I would do this:

```
$fruit = banana;

function showFruit(){
  global $fruit;
  echo $fruit;    
}
```

This would print "banana", and I could define the variable outside of the function without issue.

How about in a class?

```
$fruit = "apple";

class showFruit(){
  var $string = ?????;
  // Functions here...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: please , read http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Even in non OOP PHP you should never use `global`.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa but, but... Wordpress does it everywhere, and it's the coolest thing ever made...

Comment: Yes, I know. This was just for the sake of example. Let me explain what is happening - I am instaling an off-the-shelf package in an existing site. This package has variables defined in the main class, like MySQL database details, which differ based on whether or not the site is being loaded on my development or live server. I had a global variable set to specify whether the site is a live or test site, and I want to modify the class to load a different set of variables depending on this value. Perhaps this will shed some light...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: Joomla 1.5 relies on `global $mainframe;` instance of application Singleton all the way around.

Comment: Since when "other write crap" has become a guiding principle ?

Comment: Are we discussing variables scope on a simple example, or some best practices here? )

Comment: @SergikS: First of all we're trying to understand what TS is asking about, and then naturally we give best practices here to solve the problem w/o creating new ones (or at least keeping the new count of problems low). And if you would need to deal with joomla code actually, e.g. by developing it, you would not comment that way I assume.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
class foo {
    private $fruit = "apple";

    public function showFruit() {
        echo $this->fruit;
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
$foo->showFruit(); // Prints "apple"
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3fcFjA)